# How do show an local video using ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

I have a `Video Content/Videos/samsung.mp4`. I want to show that video but I can't seem to access it in the view, I am not sure what C# code I should use to access the resource.

This doesn't show the video:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Some site!";
    var videourl = Url.Content("/Content/Videos/samsung.mp4");
}

<h2>Some site this is!</h2>
<p>
     <video>@videourl</video>
</p>
```

Comment: now [nuget package available for HTML5 Audio & Video, Please check this link](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MVC4.Video/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<video>` is a HTML5 element and it does support MP4 videos.

But the browser may not. Which browser and version are you using?

Also, your syntax above is incorrect. The correct syntax for the video element with an MP4 video would be:

```
<video src="samsung.mp4"></video>
```

Alternatively you can serve up different formats to different browsers (which is recommended) with:

```
<video>
   <source src="samsung.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   <source src="samsung.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="samsung.webm" type="video/webm">
   Your browser doesn't support the video element
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Microsoft Web Helpers package. There is a Video helper to do just this.

More details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.helpers(v=VS.99).aspx

You can download the package from Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed it in a Quicktime player or another thats supports mp4. it doesn't have anything to do with c# more HTML/javascript.

Not sure the code needed but the above information will be enough to find it on google

Comment: Is <video> not a HTML 5 tag that supports mp4?

Comment: To be honest I had no idea that you were using HTML5 or that is had a video tag, you prompted me to Google "HTML5 video tag" I found this: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp , not sure if mp4 is supported but looks like your syntax is wrong

Comment: Also a google of "html5 video tag mp4"   returns http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp